# Conditional audio playing using AV Audio Player in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I would like to be able to play audio on pressing a button a maximum of twice.  After pressing the button twice it should no longer play audio even when pressed.  I have this code currently, but it doesn't work and I am unsure where I am going wrong:

```
var soundFileURLRef: NSURL!
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer?()
var audioCounter = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // setup for audio
    let playObjects = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("mathsinfo", withExtension: "mp3")

    self.soundFileURLRef = playObjects

    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURLRef)
    } catch _ {
        audioPlayer = nil
    }
    audioPlayer?.delegate = self
    audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
}



//function for counting times audio is played
func countAudio() {
    if ((audioPlayer?.play()) != nil) {
        ++audioCounter
    }

}

//MARK: Actions

//action for button playing the audio
@IBAction func playMathsQuestion(sender: AnyObject) {
    countAudio()
    if audioCounter < 2 {
       audioPlayer?.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `countAudio` function in your code have the side effect of playing the sound asynchronously since you call `audioPlayer?.play()`. The `audioCounter` variable is only incremented when `audioPlayer` is nil. Try this version

```
var soundFileURLRef: NSURL!
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
var audioCounter = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // setup for audio
    let playObjects = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("mathsinfo", withExtension: "mp3")

    self.soundFileURLRef = playObjects

    audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURLRef)
    audioPlayer?.delegate = self
    audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
}


//MARK: Actions

//action for button playing the audio
@IBAction func playMathsQuestion(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (audioPlayer != nil) {
        if (audioCounter < 2 && audioPlayer!.play()) {
            ++audioCounter
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that here we first check to ensure the `audioPlayer` is not nil. After this we only do the `audioPlayer!.play()` call when `audioCounter < 2`. The call to `play()` returns a boolean that is true when the audio is successfully queued for play (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/play)), and in that case we increment `audioCounter`.

I also simplified the initialization of `audioPlayer` by using the `try?` version of try which returns `nil` when the callee throws.